# Что такое IsPostBack в ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

Объясните, пожалуйста, доступно, не могу понять, где оно используется и зачем! Пожалуйста.

Answer (score 18):

В двух словах...

1. Перешли по адресу сайта. Это GET запрос. Сейчас IsPostBack = false.
2. На загрузившейся страничке нажали какую-нибудь кнопку (input, button). На сервер посылается POST запрос c данными всех элементов упарвления. Сейчас IsPostBack = true. А этот запрос и называется PostBack.

Используется в основном для того чтобы выполнить какие-то действия при первой загрузке страницы и не выполнять их при нажатии на кнопки.

Пример:

```
private void Page_Load()
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
      // Валидация не выполняется при первоначальном запросе страницы.
      Validate();
  }
}
```

Подробнее: [Page.IsPostBack Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx).

Comment: Огромное спасибо,голосовать не могу почему-то